# Translation of "It will be cold (in the room)"

Tags: traduction

"Bring your jacket, because the room is air-conditioned and it will be cold."

How to translate this?

> Apporte ta veste, car la salle est climatisée et il va faire froid.

Is it correct to say "il va faire froid" in this situation? I know it is correct to say "il fait froid", "il fait chaud", etc., for natural outdoors weather, but I'm not sure about man-made whether like this.

Comment: Whatever the source of heat or cold it is *il fait froid / chaud ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

> Apporte ta veste, car la salle est climatisée et il [y] fera froid.

or

> … et il va [y] faire froid.

The *y* is optional but makes clear it will be cold in the room.